# Inject factory using interface

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, factory

I have this factory:

```
public static class ClassFactory
{
    public static IEnumHereClass CreateClass(EnumHere type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case EnumHere.First:
                return new EnumHereFirstClass();
            case EnumHere.Second:
                return new EnumHereSecondClass();
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Looks nice. But I see problem here: I can't inject it using IoC container (unity for instance) and can't mock it. I want to make this changes (use interface to inject it and delete *static*):

```
public class ClassFactory : IClassFactory
{
    public IEnumHereClass CreateClass(EnumHere type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case EnumHere.First:
                return new EnumHereFirstClass();
            case EnumHere.Second:
                return new EnumHereSecondClass();
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

What do you think?

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: Use static factory or not? What disadvantages or misunderstanding or  do you see in my code?

Comment: For the record, [using a switch case statement inside of an abstract factory is a code smell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31950362/factory-method-with-di-and-ioc/31971691#31971691) indicating there is a problem with the design. Also, using an `Enum` to specify the type is a bad practice because it means you need to change more than one class when the enum type changes.

Comment: Also see this alternative approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31950362/factory-method-with-di-and-ioc/#31956803

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Abstract Factory Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/abstract-factory-pattern.html)

> **Intent**
>
> Abstract Factory offers the interface for creating a family of related objects, without explicitly specifying their classes.

---

I see this question has been tagged previously with [factory-method](/questions/tagged/factory-method) and now [factory](/questions/tagged/factory). Not to be confused with abstract factory.

Comment: I know about abstract fatory but I don't have "family of related objects". I just want to create object instance according to passed enum value.

Comment: You mentioned IOC container, which made me think you have 2 or more different sets of classes you want to build. Instantiate the appropriate factory for a given set - I imagine an `enum` for that too -  then call that factory as shown in the OP.