# Create instance by enum value + dependency injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, enums, factory

I have some handler classes in my application which are created in runtime according to passed enum value.  It looks like this:

```
public interface IMyHandler
{
    void Handle();
}

public class SimpleHandler : IMyHandler
{
    public void Handle()
    {
        //logic here...
    }
}

public class ComplexHandler : IMyHandler
{
    public void Handle()
    {
        //logic here...
    }
}

public enum HandlerTypes
{
    Simple,
    Complex
}

public class Hanlderfactory
{
    public IMyHandler CreateHandler(HandlerTypes type)
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case HandlerTypes.Simple:
                return new SimpleHandler();
            case HandlerTypes.Complex:
                return new ComplexHandler();
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

It's ok for me. But there is a problem here if I want to inject some components in my handlers like this:

```
public class SimpleHandler : IMyHandler
{
    public SimpleHandler(IComponentOne c1, IComponentTwo c2, IComponentThree c3)
    {
        //...
    }

    public void Handle()
    {
        //logic here...
    }
}
```

I use Unity IoC container and of course I want to use it here. But it looks ugly to call `Resolve` method here manually. Am I on wrong path? How to use both of this patterns together gracefully? Is it a single option here to call IoC container inside facotry?
**UPDATE**: I tried to use injection of delegate with `InjectionFactory` class. It works fine. But in this case if I need such factory logic in two applications I need to register this delegate and mapping between enums and classes in both applications startup:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IMyHandler, SimpleHandler>(HandlerTypes.Simple.ToString());
container.RegisterType<IMyHandler, ComplexHandler>(HandlerTypes.Complex.ToString());
container.RegisterType<Func<HandlerTypes, IMyHandler>>(new InjectionFactory(c => new Func<HandlerTypes, IMyHandler>(type => c.Resolve<IMyHandler>(type.ToString()))));
```

Comment: tip: `public class Handler : IHandlerService<IComplexHandler>` Unity can resolve type parameters

Comment: What do you mean? I have HandlerTypes.Simple in runtime and need to create instance of right class.

Comment: @AydinAdn is right;  you should make the handler abstraction generic. That will solve your problems (and much more). Take a look at [this article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Enum` with a factory is a code smell that indicates you need to do more refactoring.

An alternative is to use the [strategy pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/strategy_pattern.htm) as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31950362/factory-method-with-di-and-ioc/31971691#31971691). Note the use of `Type` instead of an `Enum` ensures you only have to change one piece of code when the design changes (you could alternatively use a string datatype).

Another alternative would be to [inject a `Func` into the factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31950362/factory-method-with-di-and-ioc#31956803) so your DI container can resolve instances.

Injecting the container into an abstract factory is a way of making a [framework extension point](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-framework/). As long as the factory is part of your [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/), this is okay.

Comment: Enum value is stored in database, Using timer application retrieves row from db and needs to instantiate appropriate handler for this row. is it bad smell? Yes, it's a strategy pattern. But it's unclear for me how can I define type of strategy class? There should be some mapping between some input data (like enum value from db) and startegy type.

Comment: All types in .NET can be identified using a string representation. You could use the [`Type.GetType(string)` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert the string to a `Type` datatype. It is this string you could store in your database, but be sure not to save the version number along with it (as would happen if you were using strong naming).