# C#/Autofac - Register ALL classes under a directory, and resolve using their string names

Tags: c#, autofac

Found this - [Autofac register and resolve with Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35975635/autofac-register-and-resolve-with-names), but I need it to be more dynamic

I have a library, where a lot of new classes will be added. Let's call them `NewClass1`, `NewClass2`, etc., and all these classes inherit `AbstractBaseClass` abstract class.

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(libraryAssembly)
            .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(AbstractBaseClass)));
```

I am able to resolve `NewClass1/2/3/...` like this

```cs
container.Resolve<NewClass1>()
```

but I need to specify the class name myself, and it cannot be a `string` name of the class.

Any pointers anyone? I am looking for something like,

```cs
container.Resolve("NewClass1")

// or

container.Resolve("NewClass2")
```

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something as below:

```
var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

containerBuilder
    .RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly())
    .Where(x => x.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ClassA)))
    .Named<ClassA>(t => t.Name);

var container = containerBuilder.Build();

var b = (ClassB)container.ResolveNamed<ClassA>("ClassB");
var c = (ClassC)container.ResolveNamed<ClassA>("ClassC");
```

You can take it further and create a factory like this:

```
containerBuilder
    .Register((context, parameters) =>
    {
        var name = parameters.TypedAs<string>();
        if (context.TryResolveNamed<ClassA>(name, out var service)) return service;
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    })
    .As<ClassA>();

... 

var factory = container.Resolve<Func<string, ClassA>>();

var b = (ClassB)factory("ClassB");
var c = (ClassC)factory("ClassC");
```

Comment: Thanks! But I wouldn't know and can't use what to typecast the resolved object to, like in your `var b = (ClassB)...` example. This part needs to be dynamic, I am hoping. Once I have `b` dynamically resolved from the name of the class, I can run methods on `b`

Comment: I typecasted it, but since you mentioned that they all will inherit from ``AbstractBaseClass`` you don't have to, you can just call methods of ``AbstractBaseClass``.

Comment: You are right, that will work for me. Thank you!