# How to read configuration values from AppSettings and inject the configuration to instances of interface

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, .net-core

Just recently, I have been trying out the new asp.net features and came across this issue. 
I know that we can read the configuration as strongly typed instance. but i have no idea how can i inject the configuration to my class in Microsoft dependency injection.

```
public interface IProvider
{
  IMyConfiguration Configuration {get;}
  Task Connect();
}

public abstract class Provider: IProvider
{
    private IMyConfiguration _myConfig;

    public Provider(IMyConfiguration config)
    {
        this._myConfig= config;
    }

    public IMyConfiguration Configuration => _myConfig;
    public abstract Task Connect();
}

public class ProviderOne:Provider
{
    public ProviderOne(IMyConfiguration  config) : base(config)
    {
    }

    public Task Connect()
    {
      //implementation
    }
}
```

configuration class:

```
public interface IMyConfiguration
{
     string TerminalId { get;set; }
     bool IsDefault {get;set;}
}
public class MyConfiguration : IMyConfiguration
{
     string TerminalId { get;set; }
     bool IsDefault {get;set;}
}
```

and then in startup.cs as i declared, it is required to pass the MyConfiguration. but i could not find a way to do so. please advice!

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.Configure<MyConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("MyConfiguration"));
  services.AddSingleton<IProvider>(new ProviderOne(//configuration)); //here is the problem
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Option 1**

First of all, you don't need `IMyConfiguration` interface. .NET Core already uses own `IOptions` interface for abstraction. When you use

```
services.Configure<MyConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("MyConfiguration"));
```

you tell the DI how to resolve next dependency: `IOptions<MyConfiguration>`

So, instead of

```
public Provider(IMyConfiguration config)
```

use

```
private MyConfiguration _myConfig;

public Provider(IOptions<MyConfiguration> options)
{
    this._myConfig = options.Value;
}
```

The same for `ProviderOne`

```
public ProviderOne(IOptions<MyConfiguration> options) : base(options)
```

---

As .NET Core DI knows how to resolve dependencies that are registered, now you can simply use next version of the method:

```
services.AddSingleton<IProvider, ProviderOne>();
```

---

**Option 2**

You may leave your code as is; directly instantiate instance of `MyConfiguration` in `ConfigureServices` method and use for ypur Provider instance creation:

```
var myConfiguration = new MyConfiguration();
Configuration.GetSection("MyConfiguration").Bind(myConfiguration);

services.AddSingleton<IProvider>(new ProviderOne(myConfiguration));
```

The main difference is that in this case, you don't use the DI container for `ProviderOne` instantiation. And so the main disadvantage is that if you need to add more dependencies for your provider (and so extend number of constructor parameters) you should resolve those dependencies in  `ConfigureServices` method as well. For more details, you may find next discussion useful: [Best way to resolve during ConfigureServices](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/issues/329).

In general, for situation when you have only one implementation of `IMyConfiguration`,  it is possible to do even so:

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyConfiguration>(myConfiguration);
services.AddSingleton<IProvider, ProviderOne>();
```

and DI container will understand how to handle that. But as built-in DI container does not allow registering multiple services and then retrieving a specific one, this is not works for you. Some people solve that problem by using the Factory pattern. You will find more in next SO question: [How to register multiple implementations of the same interface in Asp.Net Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39174989/2833802)

Comment: Good but there is one problem, lets say we have different instances of MyConfiguration and Provider, how should each provider wire to its configuration.

Comment: @Behzad ok, I have added option 2

Comment: is it good to do so ? i mean, i do really want to use the best practices in my app

Comment: @Behzad if briefly, use DI as much as possible, instead of manual instantiation. The main problem in your case is that you have more than one implementation of `IMyConfiguration` interface, but built-in ASP.NET Core DI container does not support registering multiple services and then retrieving a specific one. I have updated answer and in case if you really have a lot of different `IMyConfiguration` implementations, I suggest looking into using some additional own factory class for configuration instantiation.

Comment: @Behzad you also may use a non-default IoC in your app, which support namied dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a class with properties that has to be read from appsettings

Appsettings.json

```
{
"DecoderClientOptions":
  {
     "url":"someurl@example.com",
     "key":"A90474-kGAAP1"
  }
}
```

1.Create a model class.

```cs
     public class DecoderClientOptions
        {
            public string url { get; set; }
            public int key { get; set; }
        }
```

2. Inject dependency in Startup.cs

   ```cs
        services.Configure<DecoderClientOptions> 
        (Configuration.GetSection(nameof(DecoderClientOptions)));
   ```
3. Use the properties in other classes

   ```cs
       public class DecoderClient : IDecoderClient
       {      
           private readonly IOptions<DecoderClientOptions> _ClientOptions;

           public DecoderClient(IOptions<DecoderClientOptions> ClientOptions)
           {
               _ClientOptions = ClientOptions;
           }

         var url = _ClientOptions.Value.url;
         var key = _ClientOptions.Value.key;
   ```