# Create two singleton services that implement the same interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core project (my first) that requires two internal "sequencers" for specific tasks. The first was implemented like this:

In Startup.cs ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddSingleton<ISequencer, ProfileSequencer>();
```

And of course I have the interface and implementation defined, and it's working well. However I'm not sure how to add the second sequencer, which implements the same interface but has a slightly different implementation.

```
services.AddSingleton<ISequencer, ChargeSequencer>();
```

ASP.NET doesn't complain about this, but now when I inject ISequencer into my classes, I can't imagine how it knows which singleton to use. I suspect (but don't know for sure) that the second singleton effectively replaces the first.

There is probably some bad design decision here, so I'll accept an answer that describes how I can inject two different singletons that implement the same interface, or if necessary another reasonable approach to this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174989/how-to-register-multiple-implementations-of-the-same-interface-in-asp-net-core

Comment: Thanks for the link - I agree this is essentially a duplicate. I got hung up in my search terms on the singleton implementation since I found other solutions for different service types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to register two services of same interface - second registration would override first. But I suggest you quick solution of your problem:

1) Create nested interfaces and use them for registration:

```
ISomeSpecificSequencer : ISequencer {}
IOtherSpecificSequencer : ISequencer {}
```

2) Use factory pattern

```
interface ISequencerFactory
{
  ISequencer GetSequencer(ISequencerOptions someOptions)
}
```

So in your code you inject `ISequencerFactory` and then use some option (it could be `string`, `enum`, `Type`, etc) to determine which class you need

Comment: This is a good solution to a bad question on my part - thanks. FWIW I am rethinking this to create the sequencers in SQL/stored procedures which is probably safer than creating my own in the first place.

Comment: Are you sure that the second registration will override the first one? I am just curios about that.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin I think I tested it in the past. As I understand `IServiceCollection` class store mapping `interface > realization`. Adding interface second time will override first mapping.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late answer, but you can just inject `IEnumerable<ISequencer>` into your class or controller, and service locator will pass all the registered services under that interface