# Accessing HttpClientHandler in the same place as HttpClient is created

Tags: .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I have a service requesting an URL and validating the server SSL certificate. The code has been running smoothly with `HttpWebRequest` in full .NET framework, but now I want to migrate it to `HttpClient` and .NET Core. I can get the certificate like this (the approach is recommended in multiple blog posts and stack overflow answers):

```cs
X509Certificate2 cert = null;

var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
{
    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (request, certificate, chain, errors) =>
    {
        cert = certificate;
        return true;
    }
});

httpClient.GetAsync(...);
```

The issue here is that I constantly create new `HttpClient` instances, which isn't recommended. I want to move to `HttpClientFactory`, why I add the following in my setup code:

```cs
services
    .AddHttpClient("sslclient", x =>
    {
        ...
    })
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler
    {
        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (request, certificate, chain, errors) =>
        {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

The challenge now is that the code creates the client no longer has access to `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback`:

```cs
var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("sslclient");
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Perhaps my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51358870/configure-httpclientfactory-to-use-data-from-the-current-request-context/51460160#51460160) is helpful for you.

Comment: I don't think that it is. You are only using the HttpClient in your controller to make requests. My challenge is that I want to get the callback inside the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone at Reddit [suggested](https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnetcore/comments/cwwk1o/accessing_httpclienthandler_in_the_same_place_as/eyhooc1/?context=8&depth=9) the following solution. Once the call to `AddHttpClient` has been made, it is no longer possible to modify the `HttpClientHandler`. It is possible to share a resource, though:

```cs
var certificates= new ConcurrentDictionary<string, X509Certificate2>();
services.AddSingleton(certificates);
services
    .AddHttpClient("sslclient", x =>
    {
        ...
    })
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler
    {
        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (request, certificate, chain, errors) =>
        {
            certificates.TryAdd(request.RequestUri.Host, new X509Certificate2(certificate));
            return true;
        }
    });
```

In the code making the HTTP request, you'd need to inject the `certificates` dictionary as well. Once the request has been made, you can check for a certificate in the dictionary:

```cs
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
if (certificates.ContainsKey(uri.Host))
{
    // Happy days!
}
```

Comment: Thomas, I'm in the same predicament, porting old .NET Framework to the preferred http clients in core 2.x+ is proving to be interesting. In my case it is access to the cookie container. Great big light-bulb went off you you mentioned the container. Anything to look out for since you posted the answer?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question? You want to access the cookie container where you use the HttpClient?

Comment: Correct.I want to standardize on the usage of the HttpClientFactory and the various flavors of the httpclient that are returned.

Comment: I don't know how you would do that with HttpClient. Maybe create a new question?