# How to get access token in typed HttpClient

Tags: identityserver4, blazor, blazor-server-side

I've got a IdentityServer4/WebAPI setup and a typed HttpClient in my server-side Blazor application. I want to add the access token dynamically when a request to the API is made. But neither the `HttpContext` nor the `AuthenticationStateProvider` is accessible in the `AddHttpClient` method or in the `AddHttpMessageHandler`.

This works locally but running on the server `httpContextAccessor` is null:

```
        services.AddHttpClient<IMyClient, MyClient>((serviceProvider, client) =>
        {       
            var httpContextAccessor = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
            var accessToken = await httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken); 
        }).AddHttpMessageHandler<MyApiBearerTokenHandler>();
```

Trying to access the `AuthenticationStateProvider`

```
        services.AddHttpClient<IMyClient, MyClient>((serviceProvider, client) =>
        {       
            var authStateProvider = serviceProvider.GetService<AuthenticationStateProvider>();
        }).AddHttpMessageHandler<MyApiBearerTokenHandler>();
```

throws the following error:

> 'Cannot resolve scoped service
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthenticationStateProvider'
>   from root provider.'

How do I get the access token into `AddHttpClient`? Am I completely on the wrong track?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configure HttpClientFactory to use data from the current request context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51358870/configure-httpclientfactory-to-use-data-from-the-current-request-context)

Comment: No it doesn't but thanks anyway. I have seen that thread already and it helped me understand the topic but it does not seem to work for Blazor.