# Add Jwt token in header for every Http call using the concept of `HttpInterceptor` From angular for asp.net core web api

Tags: c#, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-httpclient

Is there any way to implement an interceptor so that I can call a microservice api from another microservices where all the http call will be intercepted & added jwt token in the header? So that, I don't have to set authorization token each time I request.

In angular there is a concept of `HttpInterceptor`. Where each http requests will be intercepted ans added jwt token in the header. Is there any way to achieve that in asp.net core web api?

Comment: Can you check this? [Another Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51358870/configure-httpclientfactory-to-use-data-from-the-current-request-context) has an accepted answer with multiple approaches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach are named clients. Here you add a preconfigured HttpClient instance to your service registry and can access this instance wherever you need it:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("GitHub", httpClient =>
{
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.github.com/");

    // using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;
    // The GitHub API requires two headers.
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(
        HeaderNames.Accept, "application/vnd.github.v3+json");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(
        HeaderNames.UserAgent, "HttpRequestsSample");
});
```

Use the `httpClient.Default*` properties.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#named-clients

The drawback is, that you don't know how requests must look like when using the instance. One approach to solve this is to create a so-called typed client. Basically a wrapper around HttpClient adding the right configuration and enforcing the correct request and response types.

```
public class CatalogService : ICatalogService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly string _remoteServiceBaseUrl;

    public CatalogService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task<Catalog> GetCatalogItems(int page, int take, int? brand, int? type)
    {
        var uri = API.Catalog.GetAllCatalogItems(_remoteServiceBaseUrl, page, take, brand, type);
        var responseString = await _httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);

        var catalog = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Catalog>(responseString);
        return catalog;
    }
}
```

(example from the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)

If you have static values (e.g. a fixed client secret), you can use options to inject them as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0

If you get your token from another service, obviously just inject this other service.

You can also configure the HttpClient when adding your typed client to the service registry:

```
services.AddHttpClient<ICatalogService, CatalogService>(client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration["BaseUrl"]);
});
```

Example from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests#multiple-ways-to-use-ihttpclientfactory

Configuring the client here is similar to angular injectors in the way, that it separates configuration and client implementation. Example: You could use the same CatalogService class with a catalog server that expects an Authorization header and a server that expects "MySpecialAuth" header without having to take care of those differences in the CatalogService class.

To show the differences in the flow...

- Angular iterceptors: use shared http client > then intercept requests based on e.g. domain
- C# clients: preconfigure clinet > then use configured instance

Side notes:

- You typically should not create new instances of HttpClient manually. Inject them using and use IHttpClientFactory in the background.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a custom `HttpClient` using inheritence which adds this Header in each request, and use this across your application

Comment: Can you please show me sample code? I also need to know what to do in `startup.cs` file and also how to get the token got from the request from UI.