# How do you resolve a specific keyed service in ASP.NET Core when using Autofac?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, autofac

I created in simple ASP.NET Core web API, Let's say I have an interface as below:

```
public interface ITestService
{
    string GetDate();
}
```

I am using Autofac to handle DI, for the above interface I have two registered types (TestService and TestComponent implementing ITestService) :

```
builder.RegisterType<TestService>().As<ITestService>().Keyed<ITestService>("service");
builder.RegisterType<TestComponent>().As<ITestService>().Keyed<ITestService>("component");
```

I know for a fact that I can register my type to use either of these bindings, and I know there is a way to get the proper type as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44891865/1324022):

```
var services = serviceProvider.GetServices<ITestService>();
var testComponent= services.First(o => o.GetType() == typeof(TestComponent));
```

Since I am using Autofac and registered my types using Keyed Services, how do I resolve the proper ITestService using IServiceProvider and the key I provided in my bindings ("service" or "component")?

Answer (score 2):

As per [documentation](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html) there are two more clean ways to resolve keyed services. You can resolve using an index:

```
public class TestServiceConsumer
{
    private ITestService testService;    

    public TestServiceConsumer(IIndex<string, ITestService> testServices)
    {
        testService = testServices["service"];
    }
}
```

It also can be done with Attribute (it seems more suitable to your case):

```
public class TestServiceConsumer
{
    private ITestService testService;    

    public TestServiceConsumer([KeyFilter("service")] ITestService testService)
    {
        this.testService = testService;
    }
}
```