# Dependency Injection: Two service subclass but how to tell which one to instantiate

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, scoping

I am using .net core for the Dependency Injection to instantiated the class.

```
class A : InterfaceA { } and class B : InterfaceA { }
```

StartUp.cs:

```
_service.AddTransient(InterfaceA, classA)
_service.AddTransient(InterfaceA, classB)
```

Controller.cs:

```
public ConstructorA (InterfaceA service) { }
```

How to tell it uses classA or classB in the ConstructorA?

Comment: Does this code run? I’m guessing you get an exception.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174989/how-to-register-multiple-implementations-of-the-same-interface-in-asp-net-core

Answer (score 1):

I dont think so your code will work.
But you can try like below.

In StartUp :

```
services.AddSingleton<classA>();  
services.AddSingleton<classB>();  


services.AddTransient<Func<string, InterfaceA>>(serviceProvider => key =>  
{  
   switch (key)  
     {  
       case "A":  
           return serviceProvider.GetService<classA>();  
       case "B":  
           return serviceProvider.GetService<classB>();  
       default:  
           throw new KeyNotFoundException();  
            }  
        });
```

In Caller method :

```
public class Caller: ICaller  
{  
    private readonly Func<string, InterfaceA> _injector;  
    public Caller(Func<string, InterfaceA> injector)  
    {  
        this._injector = injector;  
    }  

    public object Get()  
    {  
        return _injector("A").GetData();  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you create a class that have classA and classB for DI ?
I think you can create a concreteModel for ClassA and ClassB. Than you can inject this complex model with InterfaceA ?