# .NET Core keyed dependency injection

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection

Unity, Autofac and probably quite a few other Dependency injection packages all support "keyed dependency injection containers" that allow to register multiple implementations of an interface and identify them uniquely via a key (be it a string, an int, an enum or whatever else).

However, .NET Core, so far I can see at least, doesn't have such a feature and if I were to try to implement anything like this, I'd have to do a [workaround](http://stevetalkscode.co.uk/named-dependencies-part-2) or find some hacky solutions for it. I am wondering, is there a particular reason this has not been introduced in .NET Core?

Unity example:

```cs
     container.RegisterType<IService, ServiceImplementation1>("1");
     container.RegisterType<IService, ServiceImplementation2>("2");
```

Autofac example:

```cs
     builder.RegisterType<ServiceImplementation1>().Keyed<IService>("1");
     builder.RegisterType<ServiceImplementation2>().Keyed<IService>("2");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to register multiple implementations of the same interface in Asp.Net Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174989/how-to-register-multiple-implementations-of-the-same-interface-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: [Maybe one of these hacky workarounds ... or helpful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174989/how-to-register-multiple-implementations-of-the-same-interface-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: As I was saying, I am well aware of the workarounds, but I wasn't sure why this feature isn't natively implemented in .NET Core's DI container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ...,is there a particular reason this has not been introduced in .NET Core?

Short answer: **Yes**

Reference [Default service container replacement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#default-service-container-replacement-1)

> ***The built-in service container is designed to serve the needs of the framework and most consumer apps***. We recommend using the built-in container unless you need a specific feature that the built-in container doesn't support, such as:
>
> - Property injection
> - Injection based on name ***(a.k.a keyed)***
> - Child containers
> - Custom lifetime management
> - Func support for lazy initialization
> - Convention-based registration

note: *emphasis mine*

Comment: Microsoft's documentation doesn't really explain **why** it doesn't feature keyed DI, but oh well. I'll mark your answer as the correct one anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft has added keyed dependencies starting with .net8.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-8#keyed-di-services

Answer (score 0):

.NET 8 already added support for `keyed services`.

To register a keyed service, use one of the `AddKeyedSingleton()`, `AddKeyedScoped()`, or `AddKeyedTransient()` overloads, and provide an object as a key.

For example, you can register different implementations of an interface like this:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddKeyedSingleton<IService, ServiceImplementation1>("one");
builder.Services.AddKeyedSingleton<IService, ServiceImplementation2>("two");

//----------------------------------
// How to resolve services
public class TestService([FromKeyedServices("one")] IService service)
{
  // some stuff
}
```