# ASP.NET Core DI based on requesting type

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

How do I configure dependency injection in ASP.NET Core to return a certain instance depending on the type it's being injected into?

Let's say I have a simple interface,

```
public interface IHello
{
    string SayHello();
}
```

And two different implementations:

```
public class Hello : IHello
{
    public string SayHello() => "Hello...";
}

public class Hey : IHello
{
    public string SayHello() => "HEY!";
}
```

And finally I have a few classes that all depend on an instance of `IHello`:

```
public class Class1
{
    public Class1(IHello hello)
    {
    }
}

public class Class2
{
    public Class2(IHello hello)
    {
    }
}
```

Now, in `ConfigureServices` I would do something like this:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHello, Hello>();
```

to configure any class depending on `IHello` to always get the same instance of `Hello`.

**BUT: What I really want is for `Class1` to always get the same singleton instance of `Hey` and all other classes should just get an instance of `Hello`.** It could look like this in `ConfigureServices` (doesn't work, obviously):

```
services.AddSingleton<IHello, Hello>();
services.AddSingleton<IHello, Hey, Class1>(); // Doesn't work, but would be neat if it did...
```

Comment: Is the question aimed at how Dependency Injection and Services work?  If you always want Class1 to use a singleton instance of Hey, why not implement a singleton pattern for Hey and have Class1 use that?  Why get it through DI?

Comment: I think for such a scenario maybe it is better to look into autofaq?
https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html#register-by-type

Comment: This is [old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174989/how-to-register-multiple-implementations-of-the-same-interface-in-asp-net-core) but likely still relevant... You may want to just register factory for your class and resolve parameters yourself to whatever implementation you want...

Comment: @SeanSkelly I guess my question is aimed at how ASP.NET DI works, to me it seems like this SHOULD be possible and I'm puzzled it's not. It should be possible to inject different implementations into Class1, hardcoding it to Hey wouldn't be an option.

Comment: @AnkitVijay Indeed, it appears Autofac has this capability. I'll consider swapping the DI, but I would prefer not having to.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple approach. It lacks a certain elegance, but it will do what you need:

```
public static void Register(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
    serviceCollection.AddSingleton<Hello>();
    serviceCollection.AddSingleton<Hey>();

    serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ClassThatDependsOnIHello1>(serviceProvider =>
        new ClassThatDependsOnIHello1(serviceProvider.GetService<Hello>()));

    serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ClassThatDependsOnIHello2>(serviceProvider =>
        new ClassThatDependsOnIHello2(serviceProvider.GetService<Hey>()));
}
```

There are two classes that depend on `IHello`. The registration for each of them includes a function. That function resolves either `Hello` or `Hey` from the service provider and passes it to the constructor of each respective class. That way you get control over which implementation gets passed to which class.

(It's beside the point that the service provider hasn't been built yet. The function you're providing will be executed later, and the service provider passed to it will be the one that has been built from the service collection.)

A downside to this is that now your DI registration explicitly calls your constructors. That can be a nuisance because if the constructors change (maybe you inject other dependencies) then you'll have to edit this code. That's not great, but it's not uncommon.

---

Plan B would be to do as [Microsoft suggests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#default-service-container-replacement) and use another container.

### Autofac

First, add the [Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection/) NuGet package. This references Autofac and also provides the extensions needed to add an Autofac container to a service collection.

I've arranged this to focus on the way dependencies get registered with Autofac. It's similar to `IServiceCollection` and `IServiceProvider`. You create a `ContainerBuilder`, register dependencies, and then build a `Container` from it:

```
static void RegisterDependencies(this ContainerBuilder containerBuilder)
{
    containerBuilder.RegisterType<Hello>().Named<IHello>("Hello");
    containerBuilder.RegisterType<Hey>().Named<IHello>("Hey");

    containerBuilder.RegisterType<ClassThatDependsOnIHello1>().WithParameter(
        new ResolvedParameter((parameter, context) => parameter.ParameterType == typeof(IHello),
            (parameter, context) => context.ResolveNamed<IHello>("Hello")
        ));

    containerBuilder.RegisterType<ClassThatDependsOnIHello2>().WithParameter(
        new ResolvedParameter((parameter, context) => parameter.ParameterType == typeof(IHello),
            (parameter, context) => context.ResolveNamed<IHello>("Hey")
        ));
}
```

That's not really pretty either, but it sidesteps the problem of calling the constructors.

First it registers two implementations of `IHello` and gives them names.

Then it registers the two classes that depend on `IHello`. `WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter())` uses two functions:

- The first function determines whether a given parameter is the one we want to resolve. So in each case we're saying, "If the parameter to resolve is `IHello`, then resolve it using the next function."
- It then resolves `IHello` by specifying which named registration to use.

I'm not excited by how complicated that is, but it does mean that if those classes have other dependencies injected, they'll be resolved normally. You can resolve `ClassThatDependsOnIHello1` without actually calling its constructor.

You can also do it without the names:

```
static void RegisterDependencies(this ContainerBuilder containerBuilder)
{
    containerBuilder.RegisterType<Hello>();
    containerBuilder.RegisterType<Hey>();

    containerBuilder.RegisterType<ClassThatDependsOnIHello1>().WithParameter(
        new ResolvedParameter((parameter, context) => parameter.ParameterType == typeof(IHello),
            (parameter, context) => context.Resolve<Hello>()
        ));

    containerBuilder.RegisterType<ClassThatDependsOnIHello2>().WithParameter(
        new ResolvedParameter((parameter, context) => parameter.ParameterType == typeof(IHello),
            (parameter, context) => context.Resolve<Hey>()
        ));

    containerBuilder.RegisterType<SomethingElse>().As<ISomethingElse>();
}
```

We can clean that up some with an method that simplifies creating that `ResolvedParameter` because that's so hideous.

```
public static ResolvedParameter CreateResolvedParameter<TDependency, TImplementation>()
    where TDependency : class
    where TImplementation : TDependency
{
    return new ResolvedParameter((parameter, context) => parameter.ParameterType == typeof(TDependency),
        (parameter, context) => context.Resolve<TImplementation>());
}
```

Now the previous registration becomes:

```
containerBuilder.RegisterType<ClassThatDependsOnIHello1>().WithParameter(
    CreateResolvedParameter<IHello, Hello>());

containerBuilder.RegisterType<ClassThatDependsOnIHello2>().WithParameter(
    CreateResolvedParameter<IHello, Hey>());
```

Better!

That leaves the details of how you integrate it with your application, and that varies with your application. Here's [Autofac's documentation](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection) which provides more detail.

For testing purposes you can do this:

```
public static IServiceProvider CreateServiceProvider()
{
    var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
    containerBuilder.RegisterDependencies();
    var container = containerBuilder.Build();
    return new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
}
```

I like to write unit tests for this sort of thing. This method will create an `IServiceProvider` from the Autofac container, and then you can test resolving things from the container to make sure they get resolved as expected.

If you prefer another container, see if it has similar integrations to use it with Microsoft's container. You might find one you like better.

---

### Windsor

Here's a similar example using [Castle.Windsor.MsDependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Castle.Windsor.MsDependencyInjection).

```
public static class WindsorRegistrations
{
    public static IServiceProvider CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.RegisterDependencies();
        return WindsorRegistrationHelper.CreateServiceProvider(container, serviceCollection);
    }

    public static void RegisterDependencies(this IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        container.Register(
            Component.For<Hello>(),
            Component.For<Hey>(),

            Component.For<ClassThatDependsOnIHello1>()
                .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent<IHello, Hello>()),
            Component.For<ClassThatDependsOnIHello2>()
                .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent<IHello, Hey>())
        );
    }
}
```

There are two things I like about this:

- It's so much easier to read! When resolving `ClassThatDependsOnIHello2`, fulfill the dependency on `IHello` with `Hey`. Simple.
- This - `WindsorRegistrationHelper.CreateServiceProvider(container, serviceCollection)` - allows you to register dependencies with the `IServiceCollection` and include them in the service provider. So if you have existing code that registers lots of dependencies with `IServiceCollection` you can still use it. You can register other dependencies with Windsor. Then `CreateServiceProvider` mixes them all together. (Maybe Autofac has a way to do that too. I don't know.)

Comment: Thanks. Having a hard reference to the class constructors would be a huge problem in my case as there are many more dependencies to consider.

Comment: I'm working up the second part of the answer where I address that.

Comment: Hi Scott, would you mind if I update your answer to include an example of Simple Injector below the Windsor example?

Comment: Please, go for it.