# Resolve all registered services to a single interface from ASP.NET Core IOC container

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

The ASP.NET Core built-in dependency injection mechanism allows to have multiple service registrations to the same interface type:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...                   
        services.AddScoped<ICustomService, CustomService1>();
        services.AddScoped<ICustomService, CustomService2>();
        services.AddScoped<ICustomService, CustomService3>();
        ...
    }
```

While the last service registered get a precedence when the requested service is resolved:

```
public MyController(ICustomService myService) { }
```

I'm wandering how can i get the full list of registered services of a given type in my controller constructor eg. ICustomService?

Comment: This may also help you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44177920/1273882

Answer (score 2):

Make constructor argument a collection

```
public class MyController
{
    public MyController(IEnumerable<ICustomService> myServices) { }
}
```