# Resolve dependency at runtime

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, dependencies

I have a problem in .net core that I need to resolve the dependency based on the value I am getting from the API.

Interface

```
public interface IBookingSettingsDetails
{
     void GetSettings();
}
```

Class A

```
public  class ScheduleSettingsA: IBookingSettingsDetails
{
        public void GetSettings() {}
}
```

Class B

```
public  class ScheduleSettingsB: IBookingSettingsDetails
{
        public void GetSettings() {}
}
```

Resolver under startup.cs file is

```
            services.AddTransient<Func<int, IBookingSettingsDetails>>(serviceProvider => conferencingType =>
            {
                switch (conferencingType)
                {
                    case 1:
                        return serviceProvider.GetService<ScheduleSettings>();
                    case 2:
                        return serviceProvider.GetService<WebexSettings>();
                    default:
                        throw new InvalidOperationException();
                }
            });
```

Whenever I am trying to resolve dependency from the controller then I am always getting null in the resolver.

```
public class VideoConferenceController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly Func<int, IBookingSettingsDetails> _serviceAccessor;

        public VideoConferenceController(Func<int, IBookingSettingsDetails> serviceAccessor)
        {
            _serviceAccessor = serviceAccessor;
        }


        [HttpGet]
        [Route("getRandom")]
        public void getRandom(int conferenceType)
        {
            var service= _serviceAccessor(conferenceType);
            service.GetSettings();
        }
}
```

I want to resolve the dependency based on the parameter specified in the function. 
I don't want to use any third-party library like Unity. Can it be done using the above approach?

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174989/how-to-register-multiple-implementations-of-the-same-interface-in-asp-net-core ?

Comment: Yes, I tried but while resolving, I am always getting null. Startup.cs and everything looks good to me.

Comment: Thanks, the issue has been resolved. I didn't add the classes into transient. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Your welcome Mr. Jain.

Comment: You should **hardly ever** use the `GetService<T>` extension method. Instead, call `GetRequiredService<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue. I just added

```
services.AddTransient<ScheduleSettingsA>();
services.AddTransient<ScheduleSettingsB>();
```

in the startup file.