# Dependency Injection in .NET Core 3.1 with multiple implementations

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am confused about dependency injection in .NET Core where I have many intercoupled dependencies. I have a class `MyClass` implementing an interface `IMyClass` as follows:

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
     private IClass classA;
     private IClass classB;

     public MyClass (ClassA classA, ClassB classB)
     {
          this.classA = classA;
          this.classB = classB;
     }
     ....
}
```

The classes `ClassA` and `ClassB` are implementations of interface `IClass` as follows:

```
public class ClassA : IClass
{
     public ClassA (many other DI)
     {
     }
}

public class ClassB : IClass
{
     private IClass baseClass;

     public ClassB (IClass baseClass, ...)
     {
          this.baseClass = baseClass;
          ....
     }
}
```

In my startup file, how should I register my dependencies. I have tried the following, which doesn't work:

```
services.AddSingleton<ClassA>();
services.AddSingleton<IMyClass, MyClass>();
```

Can someone please explain what is the issue here and the solution to this?

Comment: You have to register ClassB too.

Comment: We need the last piece of the puzzle: how do you use ClassA and ClassB? do you use both of them as dependencies? Do you want ti use only ClassB as Decorator of ClassA?

Comment: that doesn't work either

Comment: we want to use both of them

Comment: see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77248536/836376

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to add the following in configureservices of Startup.cs:

```
var factory = ActivatorUtilities.CreateFactory(typeof(ClassB), new Type[] {typeof(IClass)});
services.AddSingleton<ClassB>(sp => factory.Invoke(sp, new object[] {sp.GetService<ClassA>()}) as ClassB); //when calling sp.GetService<ClassA> you can of course pass any implementation of IClass instead of ClassA. Of course you cannot pass ClassB beacause of infinite recursion.
```

With this solution you are telling the IoC container that you want to register a service for ClassB wich:

- will have his dependency of type "IClass" resolved as "ClassA" as it was declared in the IoC container
- will have all other dependencies normally resolved by the IoC container

Comment: this is a little complex, but thanks a lot! this worked. I am trying to understand this more :)