# How to register this dependency in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T> {
    private ISomeinterface _param;
    
    public BaseClass(ISomeinterface param) {
        _param = param;
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass<Entity> {
    public DerivedClass(ISomeinterface param) : base(param) {}
}
```

How to register this dependency in ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Do you want o register, multiple subclasses of your BaseClass and use your BaseClass as the injection parameter? If that is the case here you have an approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174989/how-to-register-multiple-implementations-of-the-same-interface-in-asp-net-core

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to register multiple implementations of the same interface in Asp.Net Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174989/how-to-register-multiple-implementations-of-the-same-interface-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: No, it doesn't belong to me. Also, the questions is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AddScoped, AddTransient and AddSingleton methods receive a serviceType and and implementationType which both are passed as `Type`, at the end both are inserted on `IServiceCollection`
Here is the implementation

```
private static IServiceCollection Add(
      IServiceCollection collection,
      Type serviceType,
      Type implementationType,
      ServiceLifetime lifetime)
    {
      ServiceDescriptor serviceDescriptor = new ServiceDescriptor(serviceType, implementationType, lifetime);
      collection.Add(serviceDescriptor);
      return collection;
    }
```

So answering your question, you can register a generic type as service, not as an implementation because you can't create an instance of a generic type. But based on your implementation you can't register your generic type without specifying on the implementation type the generic parameter. This should fail

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(BaseClass<>), typeof(DerivedClass));
```

with the following error:

> Open generic service type 'BaseClass`1[T]' requires registering an open generic implementation type. (Parameter 'descriptors')

See the definitions below

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T>
{

    public BaseClass()
    {
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass<Entity>
{
    public DerivedClass() : base() { }
}

public class DerivedClass2<T> : BaseClass<T> where T: Entity
{
   
}

public class Entity
{

}
```

Now this should work perfectly as well

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(BaseClass<>), typeof(DerivedClass2<>));
```

or

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(BaseClass<Entity>), typeof(DerivedClass2<Entity>));
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This registration is "InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'DerivedClass' while attempting to activate 'API.Controllers.SomeController'." contains error