# Multiple Elasticsearch connection in singleton object Getting one specific Singleton elastic search in controller class

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

Passing AcqClient and NcClient to the same interface

//AcqClient and NcClient are static ReadOnly Variables

```
      public static void Connection(){
        AcqClient = new ElasticClient(AcqConnection);
        NcClient= new ElasticClient(NcConnection);
```

Creating Singleton Object

```
        services.AddSingleton<IElasticClient>(AcqClient);
        services.AddSingleton<IElasticClient>(NcClient);
     }
```

Implementing in Startup.cs

```
  service.Connection(configuration)
```

On my controller class when i am doing this i am getting the last one object

```
    public class controller:Controller{
     public controller(IElasticClient elasticclient){
     
        _elasticclient=elasticlient;
        }
     }
```

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174989/how-to-register-multiple-implementations-of-the-same-interface-in-asp-net-core which will help you to get answer.

Comment: In this question classess are implementing interfaces and i want to pass connection string variables

Comment: Asad your comment does not seem to be related to question in its current state - question shows registering the same interface for 2 objects which is exactly what post suggested by @Hearty show... Could you please clarify why you believe question asks  something else? (Ideally you would [edit] question explaining how that linked question did not help in addition to clarification of what you want to achieve)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov please check i have updated the question

Comment: @Asad I don't think it changed anything... but clearly you have some problem... I just don't get what it is (you essentially claim it is not related to registering interface in the container - which is where I get lost on what you are trying to get help with)

Comment: wait a minute brother i am updating question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it like this

IServiceCollection Delegate

`public delegate IServiceCollection ServiceResolver(string key);`

Creating Elastic Search Singleton Object

```
   var firstobject = new ElasticClient(firstconnection);
   var secondobject= new ElasticClient(secondconnection);
```

Creating Object using ServiceResolver

```
    services.AddTransient<ServiceResolver>(serviceProvider => key =>
             {
                if (key== "A")
                {
                   services.AddSingleton<IElasticClient>(firstobject);
                }
                else if (key == "N")
                {
                    services.AddSingleton<IElasticClient>(secondobject);
                }
                return services;
        });
```

In One Controller Different Node Connection Of ElasticSearch

```
   private static IElasticClient _elasticClient;
        private readonly IServiceCollection _aService;

        public static string clsName = "ElasticRandDController";

        public FirstConstructor(ServiceResolver serviceAccessor)
        {
          
            _aService = serviceAccessor("N");
             var serviceProvider = _aService.BuildServiceProvider();
            _elasticClient = serviceProvider.GetService<IElasticClient>();
        }
```

In Other Controller

```
     private static IElasticClient _elasticClient;
        private readonly IServiceCollection _aService;
        public SecondConstructor(ServiceResolver serviceAccessor)
        {
            _aService = serviceAccessor("A");
            var serviceProvider = _aService.BuildServiceProvider();
            _elasticClient = serviceProvider.GetService<IElasticClient>();
        }
```