# When adding multiple dbcontext In Web API . Net core all DBSet returns null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm creating a WEB API for multiple countries, every country has a different oracle database so I create three EF context Uruguay, Peru, Argentina. When I inyect only one context everything works fine but when I inyect the three of them i recevied null object from de DBSet.

In the startup.cs I have:

[image]

how the context looks inside:
[image]

The repository that contains de EF context:
[image]

And finally the controller (when i inyect only argentina works fine, but with the three of them the function db.REG_PARAM.GetAllParams() returns null and no error:

[image]

Comment: I don't know for the DbContext, but you are injecting three times ICFERepository into the constructor of the controller, how can it know which one to pick? I am surprised you didn't get any exception btw. Here is some material about multiple interface injections : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174989/how-to-register-multiple-implementations-of-the-same-interface-in-asp-net-core

Comment: Thanks!! It was weird but no exception was thrown! Now works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because three of them are using the same interface `ICFERepository`. You cannot resolve the exact implement on that

Comment: thanks man it works fine, that totally makes sense!!