# Multiple Background Workers with different azure bus subscriptions

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, background-service

I have created a worker that can read azure bus service subscription, following examples on line.
But can't find a way to have multiple workers in the same app that would read different subscriptions and do different things.

To create my app I have added the following to my Program.cs

```
services.AddSingleton<ISubscriptionClient>(x =>
                        new SubscriptionClient(Configuration["ServiceBus:ConnectionString"],
                                                Configuration["ServiceBus:TopicName"],
                                                Configuration["ServiceBus:SubscriptionName"]));
```

and in my worker:

```
private readonly ISubscriptionClient _subscriptionClient;
```

inside ExecuteAsync

```
_subscriptionClient.RegisterMessageHandler(async (message, token) => 
        { //do stuff }
```

Is there a way i can have each background worker use a different subscription?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of injecting `ISubscriptionClient` as Singleton (do not recommend service resolver in this case because it won't solve your problem exactly), you can create readonly Global Variables in your worker role like below:

```
private readonly ISubscriptionClient _subscriptionClient1 = new SubscriptionClient(Configuration["ServiceBus:ConnectionString1"],
                                                Configuration["ServiceBus:TopicName1"],
                                             Configuration["ServiceBus:SubscriptionName1"]));

private readonly ISubscriptionClient _subscriptionClient2 = new SubscriptionClient(Configuration["ServiceBus:ConnectionString2"],
                                                Configuration["ServiceBus:TopicName2"],
                                                Configuration["ServiceBus:SubscriptionName2"]))
```

And then, use them inside `ExecutionAsync`:

```
_subscriptionClient1.RegisterMessageHandler(async (message, token) => 
        { //do stuff }
_subscriptionClient2.RegisterMessageHandler(async (message, token) => 
        { //do stuff }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to register your client in such a way that `Configuration["ServiceBus:TopicName"]` and    `Configuration["ServiceBus:SubscriptionName"]` are not “hard-coded”.

A service resolver described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44177920/59563) would work, where you’d have your implementation class taking those two parameters as constructor arguments.