# Azure Service Bus - Use multiple senders in a web API

Tags: .net-core, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

We are trying to implement Azure service bus for managing user "Work Queues"

**Background:**

We have a web UI pushing new items to a Web API which are persisted to a DB and then pushed to a Service Bus Queue. All messages have a property which denote who can work on the message. For providing a user with the ability to pick messages assigned to them, I am thinking about creating a topic with subscriptions that filter on that property.

**Approach**

To achieve the above mentioned capability:

- I need to register a sender for the queue and a sender for the topic all within the same Web API. I have tried adding the two senders as Singletons but during DI, how do I pick which sender to use ?

```
services.TryAddSingleton(implementationFactory =>
{
    var serviceBusConfiguration = implementationFactory.GetRequiredService<IMessagingServiceConfiguration>();
    var serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient(serviceBusConfiguration.IntakeQueueSendConnectionString);
    var serviceBusSender = serviceBusClient.CreateSender(serviceBusConfiguration.IntakeQueueName);
    return serviceBusSender;
});


services.TryAddSingleton(implementationFactory =>
{
    var serviceBusConfiguration = implementationFactory.GetRequiredService<IMessagingServiceConfiguration>();
    var serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient(serviceBusConfiguration.TopicConnectionString);
    var topicSender = serviceBusClient.CreateSender(serviceBusConfiguration.TopicName);
    return topicSender;
});
```

I am using the above setup to add the services as singletons and individually I am able to send and receive messages from either the topic or the queue.

How can I register both the implementations and pick which one should be injected when I use DI in the constructor to consume it.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to resolving DI registration for multiple instances of the same type, the first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174989/how-to-register-multiple-implementations-of-the-same-interface-in-asp-net-core) illustrates using a service resolver with ASP.NET Core.  To my knowledge, that is still the best approach.

For the senders, you could differentiate by checking their [EntityPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebussender.entitypath) property to identify whether they point to your queue or topic.