# How to Moq a method calls from factory

Tags: c#, moq, factory

Within Startup I have defined a factory, something similar to
[How to register multiple implementations of the same interface in Asp.Net Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174989/how-to-register-multiple-implementations-of-the-same-interface-in-asp-net-core/44177920#44177920)

Interface has 1 method Process as below.

```
//saves to db.
public interface Iprocessor
{
   void Process(List<items>);
}
```

Code to register factory within the Startup.cs

```
Func<string, IProcessor> accessor = key =>
{
    switch(key){
      case "new":
       return factory.GetService<NewProcessor>();
      case "old":
       return factory.GetService<OldProcessor>();
    }
}
```

My Service class uses this factory and I need help to mock the same.

```
private readonly  Func<string,Iprocessor> _processor;
```

_processor is assigned using DI.

```
public void ProcessRecords(List<items> items){

    List<string> types = new List<string> () { "new", "old"};
    
    foreach(var type in types)
    {
      var processor = _processor(type); 
       if(processor != null)
       {
         _processor.Process(items);
       }
    }

}
```

How do I Mock the Process method calls?

Comment: Do you need to differentiate the `old` and the `new` calls in your test?

Comment: The code should work when string of old and new is being passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make sure that everything is working fine you need to test each component separately. First you have to make sure that your `OldProcessor` and `NewProcessor` are working as expected.

After that you can focus on the `ProcessRecords`.
If I can assume that your service class receives the factory delegate inside its ctor:

```cs
class SUT
{
   private readonly Func<string,Iprocessor> _processor;
   public SUT(Func<string,Iprocessor> processor)
   {
      this._processor = processor;
   }

   public void ProcessRecords(List<items> items)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

then in your case all you need to do it to create `Iprocessor` mock
and provide a delegate which will always resolve to this mock:

```cs
[Fact]
public void TestMethod1()
{
   //Arrange
   var processorMock = new Mock<Iprocessor>();
   Func<string, Iprocessor> factory = _ => processorMock.Object;
   var input = new List<items> { ... };

   //Act
   var sut = new SUT(factory);
   sut.ProcessRecords(input);

   //Assert
   processorMock.Verify(processor => processor.Process(input), Times.Exactly(2));
}
```

Then you can verify that the `Process` method has been called twice.

---

Or if you wish you can create two separate mocks:

```cs
[Fact]
public void TestMethod2()
{
   //Arrange
   var oldProcessorMock = new Mock<Iprocessor>();
   var newProcessorMock = new Mock<Iprocessor>();
   Func<string, Iprocessor> factory = 
      t => t == "new" 
        ? newProcessorMock.Object 
        : oldProcessorMock.Objet;

   var input = new List<items> { ... };

   //Act
   var sut = new SUT(factory);
   sut.ProcessRecords(input);

   //Assert
   oldProcessorMock.Verify(processor => processor.Process(input), Times.Once);
   newProcessorMock.Verify(processor => processor.Process(input), Times.Once);
}
```

---

**UPDATE**: Setup `Process` method

```cs
oldProcessorMock
   .Setup(processor => processor.Process(It.IsAny<List<items>>())
   .Verifiable();

newProcessorMock
   .Setup(processor => processor.Process(It.IsAny<List<items>>())
   .Verifiable();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do I setup the Process method? My current implementation returns a List and is causing an exception when using a Mock.

Comment: @as2007 I've updated my answer please check that.