# Inject different loggers for controllers in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, inversion-of-control

I have defined services in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnection");
    services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddScoped<IAdsService, AdsService>();
    services.AddScoped<ILogger, ConsoleLogger>();
    services.AddScoped<ILogger, FileLogger>();
    services.AddScoped<IAdsRepository, AdsRepository>();
}
```

This is my implementation of Logger:

```
public class ConsoleLogger: ILogger
{
    public void Log(LogData data) => Console.WriteLine(data.ToString());
}

public class FileLogger : ILogger
{
    private string Path = "logs";

    public void Log(LogData data)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(Path))
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(Path);
        }

        File.AppendAllText(Path + "/logs.txt", data.ToString());
    }
}
```

I want to use different loggers for different controllers:

e.g.

```
private readonly ILogger _logger;
private readonly IAdsService _adsService;

public AdController(IAdsService adsService, ILogger logger)
{
    _adsService = adsService;
    _logger = logger;
}
```

However it only takes `FileLogger` - how to specify my controller to use `ConsoleLogger` in Startup?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to register multiple implementations of the same interface in Asp.Net Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174989/how-to-register-multiple-implementations-of-the-same-interface-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: Why use different loggers for different controllers? What purpose does that serve? And it looks like you're reinventing the logging wheel - have you looked at [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging), [Serilog](https://serilog.net/), or [NLog](https://nlog-project.org/)?

Comment: @mason for university, to test IoC

Comment: I am tryint `services.AddTransient(p => new AdController(p.GetService<IAdsService>(), new ConsoleLogger()));` but it uses FileLogger

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a feature called context-based injection, which is something that is not easily implemented with MS.DI. That's not to say it's *impossible*, but depending on your needs, it might require a lot of configuration.

One way to achieve this, though, it by configuring any component that requires an alternative logger explicitly using a lambda using the `ActivatorUtilities` class. Here's an example:

```cs
private static void AddServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // The default logger
    services.AddScoped<ILogger, FileLogger>();

    // Additional 'alternative' loggers
    services.AddScoped<ConsoleLogger>();

    // Configure a component that requires an alternative logger
    services.AddTransient<AdController>(c =>
        ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<AdController>(c,
            c.GetRequiredService<ConsoleLogger>()));
}
```

In this example:

- `FileLogger` is registered as `ILogger` allowing any 'normal' component that depends on `ILogger` to get injected with `FileLogger`.
- `ConsoleLogger` is registered as itself, allowing it to be requested als alternative logger
- `AdController` is registered using the `ActivatorUtilities` so that `ActivatorUtilities` is responsible for creating a new `AdController` where a resolved `ConsoleLogger` is supplied to `ActivatorUtilities`. This allows `ActivatorUtilities` to supply `ConsoleLogger` to the first constructor parameter that is assignable from `ConsoleLogger`. This basically means that `ConsoleLogger` is supplied to the `ILogger` argument of `AdController`.

To test this code, try this:

```cs
public interface IAdsService { }
public class AdsService : IAdsService { }
public interface ILogger { }
public class ConsoleLogger : ILogger { }
public class FileLogger : ILogger { }

public class AdController
{
    public AdController(IAdsService adsService, ILogger logger) => this.Logger = logger;

    public ILogger Logger { get; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        services.AddTransient<IAdsService, AdsService>();

        AddServices(services);

        var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        using (var scope = provider.CreateScope())
        {
            var controller =
                scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AdController>();

            Console.WriteLine(controller.Logger.GetType().Name);
        }
    }
}
```

There are several downsides to this approach, the most important being that this solution might not scale well. There is no good way to take a more convention-based approach where you say "use ConsoleLogger for any component that follows the following definition X". You must specify each component that uses an alternative logger explicitly.

If these limitations cause maintainability issues, try using a different DI Container that natively supports this feature.

Comment: Tried and  Use it then in constructor `AdController(IAdsService adsService, ILogger logger)` but it uses FIleLogger still :(

Comment: See my update. I included the exact code I used to test this. It works on my machine.