# How to set which service is used?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I added two service in Startup.cs as below,

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(ICacheManager), typeof(RedisCacheManager));
services.AddScoped(typeof(ICacheManager), typeof(InMemoryCacheManager));
```

However, I couldn't understand which one is used when I construct `ICacheManager` in a `Controller`

For example, my HomeController as below:

```
private readonly ICacheManager _cacheManager;

public HomeController(ICacheManager cacheManager)
{
    _cacheManager = cacheManager;
}
```

How can I set this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to follow one of the SOLID principles

The interface segregation principle: "Many client-specific interfaces are better than one general-purpose interface."

or

```
public interface  IRedisCacheManager: ICacheManager {}

 public class RedisCacheManager: IRedisCacheManager
```

But if you don' t want to follow SOLID principles, you can follow this link
[How to register multiple implementations of the same interface in Asp.Net Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174989/how-to-register-multiple-implementations-of-the-same-interface-in-asp-net-core)