# .NET Core Dependency Injection for multilevel, multiple implementation dependencies

Tags: dependency-injection, c#-3.0, asp.net-core-3.1, servicecollection

I have come across several posts where a single interface is implemented by multiple classes and the dependency is registered and resolved. One such post is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174989/how-to-register-multiple-implementations-of-the-same-interface-in-asp-net-core?).

But how to resolve multiple, multi-level dependencies?

For example:

```cs
public enum ShortEnum { Short, Long }

public interface ISomeValidator
{
    bool ValidateInputString(string str);
}

public class ConValidator : ISomeValidator
{
    public bool ValidateInputString(string str) => true;
}

public class DonValidator : ISomeValidator
{
    public bool ValidateInputString(string str) => false;
}

public class ConProvider : ISomeProvider 
{
    ISomeValidator conValidator; // Expects instance of ConValidator
    public ConProvider(ISomeValidator someValidator)
    {
        conValidator = someValidator;
    }
}

public class DonProvider : ISomeProvider 
{
    ISomeValidator donValidator; // Expects instance of DonValidator
    public DonProvider(ISomeValidator someValidator)
    {
        donValidator = someValidator;
    }
}
```

`ShortEnum` can be used as key. That means depending upon its value, either `ConProvider` or `DonProvider` is returned. Now, the providers have a dependency on `ISomeValidator`, which, again depending upon the key value of `ShortEnum` can be resolved as the instance of `ConValidator` or `DonValidator`.

In other words, I want to build the following two object graphs:

```cs
var provider1 = new ConProvider(new ConValidator());
var provider2 = new DonProvider(new DonValidator());
```

What is the best way to utilize .NET Core 3.1 in-built dependency injection mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to achieve what you want.

The first option is to fall back to manually wiring the object graphs by registering a delegate that composes the required object graphs completely, for instance:

```cs
services.AddTransient<ISomeProvider>(
    c => new ConProvider(new ConValidator());
services.AddTransient<ISomeProvider>(
    c => new DonProvider(new DonValidator());
```

This, however, will become quite cumbersome once those classes get other dependencies, because you would very quickly start to circumvent the DI Container completely.

So instead, as a second option, you can configure the container in such way that you only have to `new` the two providers:

```cs
// Note how these validators are -not- registered by their interface!
services.AddTransient<ConValidator>(); // Might have dependencies
services.AddTransient<DonValidator>(); // of its own

services.AddTransient<ISomeProvider>(c =>
    new ConProvider(
        someValidator: c.GetRequiredService<ConValidator>(),
        otherDependency1: c:GetRequiredService<IDependency1>());

services.AddTransient<ISomeProvider>(c =>
    new DonProvider(
        someValidator: c.GetRequiredService<DonValidator>(),
        otherDependency2: c:GetRequiredService<IDependency2>());
```

This is a more-flexible solution compared to the first. But still, changes to the constructors of `ConProvider` and `DonProvider` force you to update their registrations.

To combat this, as a third option, you can use the `ActivatorUtilities` class. It will help you in achieving Auto-Wiring, where the container figures out which dependencies are required. That might look like this:

```cs
services.AddTransient<ConValidator>();
services.AddTransient<DonValidator>();

services.AddTransient<ISomeProvider>(c =>
    ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<ConProvider>(
        c,
        c.GetRequiredService<ConValidator>());

services.AddTransient<ISomeProvider>(c =>
    ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<DonProvider>(
        c,
        c.GetRequiredService<DonValidator>());
```

`ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance` will create the requested class for you; in this case either `ConProvider` or `DonProvider`. It does so by looking at the constructor of the type and resolving all constructor parameters from the supplied `c` service provider. It resolves all dependencies from the service provider -except- the dependencies you supplied manually to the `CreateInstance` method. In the example above it will match the `ISomeValidator` dependency to the supplied `DonValidator` or `ConValidator` and inject them instead.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, you want `ConValidator` instance for `ConProvider` and `DonValidator` instance for `DonProvider` and Providers should be resolved on `ShortEnum` value.

we can modify dependencies like below

```cs
public interface ISomeProvider
{
    void Method1();
}

public interface ISomeValidator
{
    bool ValidateInputString(string str);
}

public class ConValidator : ISomeValidator
{
    public bool ValidateInputString(string str) => true;
}

public class DonValidator : ISomeValidator
{
    public bool ValidateInputString(string str) => false;
}

public class ConProvider : ISomeProvider
{
    ISomeValidator conValidator; // Expects instance of ConValidator
    public ConProvider(ValidatorResolver validatorResolver) =>
        conValidator = validatorResolver(ShortEnum.Short);

    public void Method1() => Console.WriteLine("Method1 COnProvider");
}

public class DonProvider : ISomeProvider
{
    ISomeValidator donValidator; // Expects instance of DonValidator
    public DonProvider(ValidatorResolver validatorResolver) =>
        donValidator = validatorResolver(ShortEnum.Long);

    public void Method1() => Console.WriteLine("Method1 DonProvider");
}

public enum ShortEnum { Short, Long }
```

declare delgates

```cs
public delegate ISomeProvider ProviderResolver(ShortEnum shortEnum);
public delegate ISomeValidator ValidatorResolver(ShortEnum shortEnum);
```

Consumer Service

```
public class SomeOtherService
{
    private readonly ISomeProvider _provider;
    public SomeOtherService(ProviderResolver providerResolver)
    {
        _provider = providerResolver(ShortEnum.Short);
        //OR
        _provider = providerResolver(ShortEnum.Long);
        _provider.Method1();
    }
}
```

In `ConfigureServices` method of `StartUp` class

```cs
services.AddTransient<ConValidator>();
services.AddTransient<DonValidator>();
services.AddTransient<ConProvider>();
services.AddTransient<DonProvider>();

services.AddTransient<ProviderResolver>(serviceProvider => (shortEnum) =>
{
    switch (shortEnum)
    {
        case ShortEnum.Short:
            return serviceProvider.GetService<ConProvider>();
        case ShortEnum.Long:
            return serviceProvider.GetService<DonProvider>();
        default:
            throw new KeyNotFoundException();
    }
});

services.AddTransient<ValidatorResolver>(serviceProvider => (shortEnum) =>
{
    switch(shortEnum)
    {
        case ShortEnum.Short:
            return  serviceProvider.GetService<ConValidator>();
        case ShortEnum.Long:
            return serviceProvider.GetService<DonValidator>();
        default:
            throw new KeyNotFoundException();
    }
});

services.AddTransient<SomeOtherService>();
```