# How to supply dependencies to classes that are created by a factory class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection

Let's say I have an interface named `ICustomer` that defines one method `startProcessing()`:

```
interface ICustomer
{
    void startProcessing(byte[] data);
}
```

Now, I have multiple concrete classes like `ProductA_User` and `ProductB_User`. Each one has different properties but they all implement `ICustomer` as they are all customers:

```
class ProductA_User : ICustomer
{
    string _name;
    IRepository _repo;
    public ProductA_User(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }
    
    public void startProcessing(byte[] data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_name);
        var temp = _repo.Get<VModel>(filter: x.CName == _name).ToList();
    }
}

class ProductB_User : ICustomer
{
    public void startProcessing(byte[] data)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I am invoking a shared method in a factory class named `MemberFactory` and creating object based on `productType`.

```
enum ProductTypeEnum { ProductA, ProductB }

class MemberFactory
{
    ICustomer Create(ProductTypeEnum productType)
    {
        switch (productType)
        {
            case ProductTypeEnum.ProductA: return new ProductA_User("Steve");
            case ProductTypeEnum.ProductB: return new ProductB_User();
            default: return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I give it as param of the enum. Since each concrete class is different but implements `ICustomer`, I am able to return an instance that implements `ICustomer`. In `ProductA_User()` I am trying to inject `_repo` which is nothing but EF repo.

what I should do? I don't want to pass extra parameter (`_repo`) to create object of class. how can I get any injection done to my concreate class?

Comment: Have you seen [IServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceproviderserviceextensions.getrequiredservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) ?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/39174989/982149

Comment: It's unclear how we're supposed to get an instance of `IRepository` if we're not going to instantiate it within `MemberFactory.Create` or get it as input. Are you perhaps asking about how to configure a complete DI framework? If so, I think you need to do some investigation first, as that is too broad a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhere you have a class that needs an `ICustomer`. You don't want that class to know anything about the implementation of `ICustomer`, so you're using `MemberFactory`.

But if the class that needs `ICustomer` has to create `MemberFactory` and pass arguments to it like an `IRepository`, then you're back to the same problem again. The class that needs `ICustomer` shouldn't know that some implemenations of `ICustomer` need an `IRepository`.

There are a lot of approaches to this. I'll go with a simple and direct one.

First, create an interface for `MemberFactory`:

```cs
interface IMemberFactory
{
    ICustomer Create(ProductTypeEnum productType)
}
```

Change the declaration of `MemberFactory` so that it implements the interface:

```cs
class MemberFactory : IMemberFactory
```

Wherever you were injecting `MemberFactory`, inject `IMemberFactory` instead.
Now the class that depends on `IMemberFactory` won't know anything about its implementation. It just knows that it has an `IMemberFactory` and calls its `Create` method.

Then, inject the `IRepository` into the implementation, `MemberFactory`.

```cs
class MemberFactory
{
    private readonly IRepository _repository;

    public MemberFactory(IRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    ICustomer Create(ProductTypeEnum productType)
    {
        switch (productType)
        {
            case ProductTypeEnum.ProductA: return new ProductA_User("Steve");
            case ProductTypeEnum.ProductB: return new ProductB_User();
            default: return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Now if `MemberFactory` needs an `IRepository` to create certain types of `ICustomer`, it has one. This is not perfect. It could get out of hand if we added more and more dependencies this way. But it's a start.

Then, whatever type needs the `IMemberFactory` to create `ICustomer`, inject the `IMemberFactory` into that:

```cs
class SomeClassThatNeedsMemberFactory
{
    private readonly IMemberFactory _memberFactory;

    public SomeClassThatNeedsMemberFactory(IMemberFactory memberFactory)
    {
        _memberFactory = memberFactory;
    }
}
```

Now each class has its dependencies injected into it. As a result, a class isn't responsible for creating its own dependencies. That means it doesn't know anything about the concrete implementation of the dependencies. `SomeClassThatNeedsMemberFactory` doesn't know that the concrete implementation might need an `IRepository`. All it knows about `IMemberFactory` is the interface.

That's a big part of dependency injection. Now if we change the implementation of `IMemberFactory`, its consumers don't need to know about it. They don't know what gets passed to its constructor.

It also makes each class easier to test. If you're testing `SomeClassThatNeedsMemberFactory`, you can mock `IRespository`.

---

I haven't mentioned dependency injection/IoC containers yet because you didn't ask about them, and because they aren't actually central to the concept of dependency injection. Dependency injection is about constructing classes or methods so that they *receive* dependencies instead of *creating* them - all the stuff above. A container just helps us to manage all that.

Suppose we're working with `IServiceCollection`/`IServiceProvider` which is sort of the default container these days for .NET applications.

We can do this if we're working in the `Startup` class of a web application, or something similar for other application types.

```cs
void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<SomeClassThatNeedsMemberFactory>();
    services.AddScoped<IMemberFactory, MemberFactory>();
    services.AddScoped<IRepository, SomeConcreteRepository>();
}
```

This tells the service collection

- We're going to ask it to create instances of `SomeClassThatNeedsMemberFactory`.
- If it's creating anything that needs an instance of `IMemberFactory`, create an instance of `MemberFactory`.
- If it's creating anything that needs an instance of `IRepository`, use `SomeConcreteRepository`.

Now suppose the application needs to create an instance of a Web API controller, and we've injected `SomeClassThatNeedsMemberFactory` of that controller. The service provider (dependency injection/IoC container) will say

- I need to create an instance of `FooController`. The constructor says that it needs an instance of `SomeClassThatNeedsMemberFactory`, so I'll create one of those.
- Wait, the constructor for `SomeClassThatNeedsMemberFactory` needs an instance of `IMemberFactory`. When I'm asked for `IMemberFactory` I use `MemberFactory`, so I'll create one of those.
- Wait, the constructor for `MemberFactory` needs an instance of `IRepository`. I'll create an instance of `SomeConcreteRepository`.

As long as we've told it what types to use, it can create complex objects where the dependencies have dependencies that need more dependencies, and so on. But we don't have to think so hard about that. We can just look at one class at a time and pay attention to what dependencies it needs as we're writing it, working on it, or testing it.

That's why containers are so popular. We could do all this without them, but it's harder. They are not, however, what dependency injection is all about. They just enable it.

Comment: Thanks @Scott for your answer that make lot of sense, but I am still confused where should "void startProcessing(byte[] data);" will go ? the method which declared in ICustomer

Comment: That's a different question. As I answered I just assumed that the methods were where you wanted them. I don't know what it does. I don't know what that method does. There's really no way for me to know where that method should be.

Comment: I believe I have not explained my question properly here, sorry for that @Scott. I will try to put exact issue properly which I am facing in different question. as you have answered for this exactly as per my question. Thanks Again

Comment: I have added another question for what I am facing issue with. If you can please take a look.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73113990/how-to-apply-dependency-injection-with-static-class-and-method?noredirect=1#comment129130863_73113990