# .NET MAUI, Azure B2C, different user flows with Multiple Named IPublicClientApplication Instances

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, maui

I'm working on a .NET MAUI application that uses Azure AD B2C for authentication.

I have multiple Azure AD B2C policies in my application (SignUp that works fine and want to add password reset policy), and I need to use different instances of `IPublicClientApplication` for different policies (since they are using different user flows).

I've tried several approaches to configure the dependency injection, but I'm encountering issues where both services end up using the same `IPublicClientApplication` instance.

Here is the service for sign in that works fine:

```cs
public class AuthServiceB2CSignInSignUp : IAuthService
{
    private readonly IPublicClientApplication _signInApp;

    public AuthServiceB2CSignInSignUp(IPublicClientApplication signInApp)
    {
        _signInApp = signInApp;
    }
    public Task<AuthenticationResult?> SignInInteractively(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return _signInApp
               .AcquireTokenInteractive(Constants.Scopes)
               .ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    public async Task<AuthenticationResult?> AcquireTokenSilent(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            var accounts = await _signInApp.GetAccountsAsync(Constants.SignInPolicy);
            var firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();
            if (firstAccount is null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return await _signInApp.AcquireTokenSilent(Constants.Scopes, firstAccount)
                                             .ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public async Task LogoutAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var accounts = await _signInApp.GetAccountsAsync();
        foreach (var account in accounts)
        {
            await _signInApp.RemoveAsync(account);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the password reset that also works fine if I run it on its own:

```cs
public class AuthServiceB2CResetPassword : IAuthServiceB2CResetPassword
{
    private readonly IPublicClientApplication _resetApp;
    public AuthServiceB2CResetPassword(IPublicClientApplication resetApp)
    {
         _resetApp = resetApp;
    }
    public Task<AuthenticationResult?> SignInInteractively(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return _resetApp
               .AcquireTokenInteractive(Constants.Scopes)
               .ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    public async Task<AuthenticationResult?> AcquireTokenSilent(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            var accounts = await _resetApp.GetAccountsAsync(Constants.SignInPolicy);
            var firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();
            if (firstAccount is null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return await _resetApp.AcquireTokenSilent(Constants.Scopes, firstAccount)
                                             .ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the way I am registering them:

```cs
mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthServiceB2CSignInSignUp>();
mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddScoped<IPublicClientApplication>(sp =>
{
    var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create(Constants.ClientId)
        .WithIosKeychainSecurityGroup(Constants.IosKeychainSecurityGroups)
        .WithRedirectUri($"msal{Constants.ClientId}://auth")
         .WithB2CAuthority(Constants.AuthoritySignIn)
        .Build();
    return app;
});


mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthServiceB2CResetPassword, AuthServiceB2CResetPassword>();
mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddScoped<IPublicClientApplication>(sp =>
{
    var passwordResetApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create(Constants.ClientId)
        .WithIosKeychainSecurityGroup(Constants.IosKeychainSecurityGroups)
        .WithRedirectUri($"msal{Constants.ClientId}://auth")
        .WithB2CAuthority(Constants.AuthorityPasswordReset)
        .Build();

    return passwordResetApp;
});
```

In my login view model I am injecting them in the constructor:

```cs
private readonly IAuthService _signupService;
private readonly IAuthServiceB2CResetPassword _passwordResetService;

public LoginViewModel(IAuthService signupService, IAuthServiceB2CResetPassword passwordResetService)
{
    _signupService = signupService;     
    _passwordResetService = passwordResetService;
}

//do something here
```

However no matter what the last registration instance of `IPublicClientApplication` always overrides the other one, since `PublicClientApplication` comes from `Microsoft.Identity.Client` I don't really understand the approach I should take in order to have two different objects of `IPublicClientApplication`, one for password reset and one for sign in sign up.

I tried to change the order but that didn't help either, despite configuring named instances of `IPublicClientApplication`, both services (`_signupService` and `_passwordResetService`) end up using the same `IPublicClientApplication` instance.

I've tried naming the registration, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. Is there a limitation in .NET MAUI's dependency injection system that prevents this kind of setup, or am I missing something in my configuration?

What is the correct way to configure dependency injection for multiple named `IPublicClientApplication` instances for different services in a .NET MAUI application? I have also tried to find some official Azure B2C MAUI examples but the one in [Azure-Samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-dotnetcore-maui/tree/main) doesn't even implement the password reset, only signin signup. I would like to implement both at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't MAUI-specific, it's just how the [Microsoft-provided .NET dependency injection system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection) works.

With the Microsoft system when you register additional implementations for the same interface (with some caveats) it does add all implementations to the service collection *but* it will only return those implementation if you inject them as `IEnumerable<T>`. If you just inject a single interface then it will always be the last implementation registered.

For example:

```cs
// during service registration
builder.Services.AddTransient<IMyDependency, MyDependencyA>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IMyDependency, MyDependencyB>();

// when injecting multiple implementations into a service
public class MyServiceWithMultipleDependencies
{
    public MyServiceWithMultipleDependencies(IEnumerable<IMyDependency> dependencies)
    {
        /*
         * dependencies will contain two items: MyDependencyA and MyDependencyB
         * the implementations will be enumerated in the order they were registered
         */
    }
}

// when injecting a single implementations into a service
public class MyServiceWithOneDependency
{
    public MyServiceWithOneDependency(IMyDependency dependency)
    {
        // dependency will be MyDependencyB, the last implementation registered for IMyDependency
    }
}

// still counts as injecting a single implementations into a service
public class MyServiceWithOneDependency
{
    public MyServiceWithOneDependency(IMyDependency dependencyA, IMyDependency dependency2)
    {
        /* dependencyA will be MyDependencyB, the last implementation registered for IMyDependency
         * dependency2 will be MyDependencyB, the last implementation registered for IMyDependency
         *
         * The names of the parameters have no effect on the dependencies 
         * injected, they're just labels that make sense in the context 
         * of the service the dependency is injected into.
         */
    }
}
```

If you need to inject a specific implementation in the way you describe then you could use the Microsoft DI system as in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44177920/60340), or you could integrate more advanced DI container such as [Autofac](https://autofac.org/) which supports [named services](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html#named-services) and [the factory pattern](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html).

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Dave D advice I refactored using the factory pattern(also the link to that post was very useful) I will put it here in case someone wants to reuse.

```
 public class PublicClientApplicationFactory
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<string, IPublicClientApplication> _configuredApps = new Dictionary<string, IPublicClientApplication>();

        public IPublicClientApplication GetClientApplication(string configurationName)
        {
            // Create and configure the app based on the specified configuration
            var app = CreateAndConfigureClientApplication(configurationName);
            _configuredApps.Add(configurationName, app);

            return app;
        }

        private IPublicClientApplication CreateAndConfigureClientApplication(string configurationName)
        {
            switch (configurationName)
            {
                case "SignIn":
                    return PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                        .Create(Constants.ClientId)
                        .WithIosKeychainSecurityGroup(Constants.IosKeychainSecurityGroups)
                        .WithRedirectUri($"msal{Constants.ClientId}://auth")
                        .WithB2CAuthority(Constants.AuthoritySignIn)
                        .Build();

                case "PasswordReset":
                    return PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                        .Create(Constants.ClientId)
                        .WithIosKeychainSecurityGroup(Constants.IosKeychainSecurityGroups)
                        .WithRedirectUri($"msal{Constants.ClientId}://auth")
                        .WithB2CAuthority(Constants.AuthorityPasswordReset)
                        .Build();

                default:
                    throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unknown configuration: {configurationName}");
            }
        }
    }
```

individual classes for each user flow

```
 public class AuthServiceB2CSignInSignUp : IAuthService
    {
        private readonly IPublicClientApplication _signInApp;

        public AuthServiceB2CSignInSignUp(PublicClientApplicationFactory appFactory)
        {
            _signInApp = appFactory.GetClientApplication("SignIn");
        }
//methods here
```

password reset

```
 public class AuthServiceB2CResetPassword : IAuthServiceB2CResetPassword
    {
        private readonly IPublicClientApplication _resetApp;

        public AuthServiceB2CResetPassword(PublicClientApplicationFactory appFactory)
        {
            _resetApp = appFactory.GetClientApplication("PasswordReset");
        }
```

registration like this

```
   mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddSingleton<PublicClientApplicationFactory>();
        mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthServiceB2CSignInSignUp>();
        mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthServiceB2CResetPassword, AuthServiceB2CResetPassword>();
```

each service can be then accessed individually after injecting