# How to register class using multi-level inheritance with interface

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dependency-injection

In my .NET Core 8 API having interfaces like these:-

// Interfaces

```
public interface ITokenService { 
   string Generate(UserDetail user);
}

public interface IAccessTokenService : ITokenService { }

public interface IRefreshTokenService : ITokenService { }
      
}
```

RefreshTokenService class:-

```
public class RefreshTokenService : IRefreshTokenService { 

       private readonly ITokenGenerator _tokenGenerator;
 private readonly JWTSettings _jwtSettings;
 public RefreshTokenService(IOptions<JWTSettings> settings, ITokenGenerator tokenGenerator)
 => (_tokenGenerator, _jwtSettings) = (tokenGenerator, settings.Value);

 public string Generate(UserDetail user) => _tokenGenerator.Generate(_jwtSettings.RefreshTokenSecret, _jwtSettings.Issuer, _jwtSettings.Audience, _jwtSettings.RefreshTokenExpiry);
}
```

AccessTokenService class:-

```
   public class AccessTokenService : IAccessTokenService
   {
      private readonly ITokenGenerator _tokenGenerator;
      private readonly JWTSettings _jwtSettings;
      public AccessTokenService(ITokenGenerator tokenGenerator, JWTSettings jwtSettings) =>
             (_tokenGenerator, _jwtSettings) = (tokenGenerator, jwtSettings);
    
    public string Generate(UserDetail user)
    {
        List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>() {};

        return _tokenGenerator.Generate(_jwtSettings.AccessTokenSecret, _jwtSettings.Issuer, _jwtSettings.Audience, _jwtSettings.RefreshTokenExpiry,claims);
    }
}
```

And I have registered these classes in `Statup.cs`

```
services.AddScoped<ITokenService, RefreshTokenService>();
services.AddScoped<ITokenService, AccessTokenService>();

services.AddTransient<IAccessTokenService, AccessTokenService>();
services.AddTransient<IRefreshTokenService, RefreshTokenService>(); 
--------------Other services here---------------
```

Service class where I am using access token and refresh token classes

```
public class SomeClass : ISomeService{
    private readonly IRefreshTokenService _refreshTokenService;
    private readonly IAccessTokenService _accessTokenService;
    
     public SomeClass(IRefreshTokenService refreshTokenService, 
      IAccessTokenService accessTokenService){
           _refreshTokenService =  refreshTokenService;
           _accessTokenService = accessTokenService;
      }
}
```

But getting error:

> Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> API.Services.IAccessTokenService Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: Services.AccessTokenService': Unable to resolve service for type 'Models.JWTSettings' while attempting to activate 'Services.AccessTokenService`. How to resolve depencency here.

Comment: what is exact message that you are getting ?

Comment: You have registered `ITokenService` multiple times! So What do you expect from dependency contains to give you back when you ask for `ITokenService`  !!

Comment: How are you trying to resolve the dependency? Show that code.

Comment: you can try [Keyed DI services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174989/how-to-register-multiple-implementations-of-the-same-interface-in-asp-net-core/77007913#77007913)

Comment: Please show the full error text and what you are trying to resolve.

Comment: And how do you register `JWTSettings`? Is it something like `Configure<JWTSettings>(...)`? If yes then you need to resolve `IOptions<JWTSettings>`, not `JWTSettings`.

Comment: It appears that in `AccessTokenService` you should be injecting `IOptions<JWTSettings>`, not `JWTSettings`, as you do in `RefreshTokenService`.

Comment: Jwt settings it was working on other classes its registered in startup class already

Comment: @GhanshyamSingh please show how are you registering the settings. And where and how are you resolving `ISomeService`.

Comment: `services.AddTransient<ISomeService, SomeService>();`  @GuruStron like this

Comment: @GhanshyamSingh `services.AddTransient<ISomeService, SomeService>();` this clearly does not register settings =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that are using the [options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options) for your configuration then you need to resolve one for the `IOptions...<TOptions>` interfaces, usually `IOptions<TOptions>` itself instead of directly resolving the configuration class. For example:

```
public AccessTokenService(ITokenGenerator tokenGenerator, IOptions<JWTSettings> jwtSettingsOpts) =>
     (_tokenGenerator, _jwtSettings) = (tokenGenerator, jwtSettingsOpts.Value);
```

Note that in `RefreshTokenService` you are doing exactly that:

```
public RefreshTokenService(IOptions<JWTSettings> settings, ITokenGenerator tokenGenerator) 
=> (_tokenGenerator, _jwtSettings) = (tokenGenerator, settings.Value);
```

Comment: @Gutu found the issue. I was not using IOptions and directly using JWTSettings class which is causing the issue. Thanks.