# How to register multiple services implementing same interface and inject into controller constructor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi

I have two services that implement the same interface. Following the answer [How to register multiple implementations of the same interface in Asp.Net Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174989/how-to-register-multiple-implementations-of-the-same-interface-in-asp-net-core) I have simplified code like

**Interface:**

```
public interface ICheckService
{
    Method1();
    Task Method2();
}
```

**CheckerService:**

```
public class CheckerService : ICheckService
{
    private readonly DapperContext _context;
    private readonly ILogger<CheckerService> _logger;

    public CheckerService(DapperContext context,ILogger<CheckerService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

**DesignerService:**

```
public class DesignerService : ICheckService
{
    private readonly DapperContext _context;
    private readonly ILogger<DesignerService> _logger;

    public DesignerService(DapperContext context,ILogger<DesignerService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

In my **Startup.cs** file:

```
public delegate ICheckService ServiceResolver(string key);
...
services.AddScoped<ICheckService, DesignerService>();
services.AddScoped<ICheckService, CheckerService>();
services.AddScope<ServiceResolver>(serviceProvider => key =>
{
switch (key)
{
    case "DesignerService":
        return serviceProvider.GetService<DesignerService>();

    case "CheckerService":
        return serviceProvider.GetService<CheckerService>();

    default:
        throw new KeyNotFoundException();
}
});
```

And in the **Controller:**

```
private readonly ICheckService _checklistService;

public DesignerController(ServiceResolver serviceAccessor)
{
    _checklistService = serviceAccessor("DesignerService");
}
```

But after launching the code, I find that the returned service is **null**. But if I remove the switch code and change controller constructor to

```
public DesignerController(ICheckService checkService)
{
    _checklistService = checkService;
}
```

the everything is fine.

Could someone tell me where I did wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following registrations instead:

```cs
services.AddScoped<DesignerService>();
services.AddScoped<CheckerService>();
```

Notice that both `DesignerService` and `CheckerService` are no longer registered by their interface, but rather their concrete type. This is needed, because you request them by their concrete type.