C# ,ASP.NET Core 6, hosting multiple APIs in Windows service
Update: More specifically, I'd like to know how to tell the server how to listen so a specific URL with the same domain, but different paths, can point to only 1 of the multiple Windows Services hosting the API application.
If I use "https://{server name}/{env}" it should send requests to the the application for the same environment - just as in IIS.
I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API hosted in a Windows service that is working, but I have yet to find an effective means to host multiple instances of the same application, but for different environments, on the same server.
The server environment cannot change - it is Windows Server 2019.
I have basic Kestrel settings with a local certificate applied.
Does anyone have any solid ideas to run multiple instances of an ASP.NET Core Web API application within 1 or more Windows services on the same Windows Server operating system?
I'd like to be sure to explore all probable options before changing the paradigm for the how the hosted API functions in general under a single type of environment.
All attempts to use the normal ways to set the base path do not work. It does not operate the same way outside of IIS or as an App Service in Azure.

You may need one service that calls the other services.  See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174989/how-to-register-multiple-implementations-of-the-same-interface-in-asp-net-core

IIS is acting as a reverse proxy, you could do the same with nginx or some other proxy to forward requests to the correct process. With each service bound to their own localhost port.

After stepping away, I made one more attempt:

First, I included the https://*/{app-path} in the Kestrel appsettings against the Url value, without the port number. This threw an error indicating this should not be done, but I should use the app.UsePathBase("{app-path}") method. (Not surprising. This is what I expected.)
Next, I reset the Url value in the Kestrel settings to the https://*:{port} value. I then made another attempt to use app.UsePathBase(), but I added it immediately after executing builder.Build().

This worked on my local machine, finally. I can load the root response page and Swagger at the app-path URL.
Next Steps: To test on the server with a second instance with its own port and base path to make sure they both work concurrently.

The only way you're going to be able to run multiple instances of your application on the same machine is to use a different port.
Oddly enough this is the 2nd time today that I've had to find this excellent article on how to set the URLs for a .NET application: https://andrewlock.net/8-ways-to-set-the-urls-for-an-aspnetcore-app/
My preferred way to do it is in appsettings.json:
{
  "urls": "http://*:5003", //  Specify the URL
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

And then I think you're going to have to use a reverse proxy such an nginx or YARP to surface that application under different paths within a domain.
