# Complex dependency chain using Dependency Injection

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core

Using ASP.NET Core, in file "Startup.cs" I can register dependencies using the method ConfigureServices, and add to the object "services".  How do I configure multiple concrete implementations of the interface such that runtime resolution will determine the correct concrete implementation (such as by name)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dependency injection resolving by name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39072001/dependency-injection-resolving-by-name)

Comment: Thanks @ademcaglin - will need to spend some time to verify this is a dup of my question.