# Can't Enqueue my Job in hangfire server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hangfire, hangfire-autofac

I am working on enqueue jobs using hangfire in my application.

my enqueue job statement is given below,

```
string jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => 
     strategy.get(typeof(_service.Engine.Summary), cpdata));
```

when this will enqueue my job successfully but got the error message in State table like this,

> "FailedAt": "2018-03-21T13:14:46.0172303Z",   "ExceptionType":
>   "System.MissingMethodException",   "ExceptionMessage": "No
>   parameterless constructor defined for this object.",
>   "ExceptionDetails": "System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless
>   constructor defined for this object.\r\n   at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)\r\n
>   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)\r\n   at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)\r\n   at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)\r\n   at
>   Hangfire.JobActivator.SimpleJobActivatorScope.Resolve(Type type)\r\n
>   at Hangfire.Server.CoreBackgroundJobPerformer.Perform(PerformContext
>   context)\r\n   at
>   Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.b__0()\r\n
>   at
>   Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.InvokePerformFilter(IServerFilter
>   filter, PerformingContext preContext, Func 1 continuation)\r\n   at
>   Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.PerformJobWithFilters(PerformContext
>   context, IEnumerable`1 filters)\r\n   at
>   Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.Perform(PerformContext
>   context)\r\n   at
>   Hangfire.Server.Worker.PerformJob(BackgroundProcessContext context,
>   IStorageConnection connection, String jobId)"

Is this DI issue that creating this type of error?

i used calling method in Enqueue using the reference of this link

[Factory method with DI and IOC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31950362/factory-method-with-di-and-ioc/31971691#31971691)

For Example,

```
var strategy = new CarStrategy(new ICarFactory[] {
    new Car1Factory(dep1, dep2, dep3),
    new Car2Factory(dep4, dep5, dep6),
    new Car3Factory(dep7, dep8, dep9)
});
```

My Code is Like this,

```
var strategy = new Strategy(new ICP[] {
                new _Services.Engine.Detail.Detail(),
                new _1Services.Engine.Summary.Summary(),
                });

var CP = PrepareCPModelForEngine(c);

string jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => 
strategy.get(typeof(_Services.Engine.Summary.Summary), cp));
```

Comment: Does your Summary class has a parameterless constructor ? Does not look like a HangFire problem to me.

Comment: Thanx for your reply...I have defined parameterless constructor  in my summary class as u said... but still got the same issue

Comment: I don't think we'll be able to help you further if we don't have more code, especially if the problem is hiding in your Strategy implementation.

Comment: yes i have added my code in the question

Comment: For Hangfire, it is best to make the job as simple as possible. I suggest create a simple job that will actually instantiate the proper handler as required at the job's runtime. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: ok... thanx for your help!